# Django how to set value of hidden input in template

Tags: python, django

How to set value of `who` and `image` in template?

```
class CommentForm(ModelForm):
    who = forms.CharField(widget=forms.HiddenInput())
    image = forms.ImageField(widget=forms.HiddenInput())

    class Meta:
        model = Comments
        fields = ['who', 'image', 'content']
```

It doesn't work (raw text):

```
<form method='POST' action=''>
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% render_field comment_form.content class="form-control form-control-sm" placeholder='Comment..' %}
    {% render_field comment_form.who class="form-control form-control-sm" value='{{ request.user.profile.pk }}' %}
    {% render_field comment_form.image class="form-control form-control-sm" value='{{ image.pk }}' %}
    <input class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" type="submit" value="Add comment">
</form>
```

My `views.py`:

```
class ProfileView(DetailView):
    comment_form = CommentForm()
    queryset = Profile.objects.all()
    context_object_name = 'me'
    template_name = 'profile.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(ProfileView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['comment_form'] = self.comment_form
        return context
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to set [the `initial` property](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/forms/fields/#initial) of the form field, after you've instantiated the form in your view. Like so:

```
class ProfileView(DetailView):
    comment_form = CommentForm()
    queryset = Profile.objects.all()
    context_object_name = 'me'
    template_name = 'profile.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(ProfileView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['comment_form'] = self.comment_form
        # This sets the initial value for the field:
        context['comment_form'].fields['who'].initial = self.request.user.profile.pk
        return context
```

Answer (score 4):

It is an old question, but I will put my answers to try to help those in need.
You can set initial value dynamical in your view

link in Django documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/forms/api/#dynamic-initial-values

> Use initial to declare the initial value of form fields at runtime. For example, you might want to fill in a username field with the username of the current session.
>
> To accomplish this, use the initial argument to a Form. This argument, if given, should be a dictionary mapping field names to initial values. Only include the fields for which you’re specifying an initial value; it’s not necessary to include every field in your form

eg

```
comment_form = CommentForm(initial={'who ': request.user.profile.pk})
```

Comment: This worked perfectly for me. I had to add the initial={..} in the GET method for my View class in case anyone is wondering about that.

Answer (score 2):

You can do some thing like this. This is a pure HTML approach.
Inside the from add the

```
<input type="hidden" name="content" value="{{value}}">
```

Put the `field` inside the `name` attribute and set the value to anything you want inside the `value` attribute.

Comment: This did not work for me with Django 3.2.13 ... Luciano's worked perfectly.

Comment: Thank you. I have been using: "<input type="text" value="{{value}}" name="content" hidden="hidden"/>". Partha's answer is more direct and clear.

Answer (score 1):

```
<form method='POST' action=''>
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% render_field comment_form.content class="form-control form-control-sm" placeholder='Comment..' %}
    {% render_field comment_form.who class="form-control form-control-sm" value='{{ comment_form.who }}' %}
    {% render_field comment_form.image class="form-control form-control-sm" value='{{ comment_form.image }}' %}
    <input class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" type="submit" value="Add comment">
</form>
```